# Using GNU coreutils on iterm2 disables LSCOLORS

Tags: gnu, ls, iterm2, ls-colors

I am using iterm2 on Mac OS Catalina, however, I prefer all the GNU utils over the FreeBSD ones. Specifically, the `cp` command in FreeBSD lacks the `-t` option to specify the target, which I like to use when piping `find | xargs cp -t <dest>`.

So I used brew to install the GNU core utils as described in this post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities

And so, I now have the GNU versions of the common shell tools, my `ls` is now using the `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls`. The downside is that my `ls` colors are now gone. See below:

[env and command outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXKub.png)

I can obviously get around this by aliasing my `ls` command with the `/bin/ls` but I am wondering if there is a better way. How can I get the GNU `ls` to recognize my environment settings for colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Looks like all GNU `ls` needed was `--color=auto`

So this alias in my `.zshrc` worked -

`alias ls='ls -G --color=auto'`

I assume the same should work in `.bashrc` (not tested).

Comment: This works for both MacOS `ls` and coreutils, so safe to add to your .zshrc or .bashrc! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dircolors to change the coreutil ls output. This link has details on how to use it. https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html